# Use of top over the subquery with order by inside the subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Select top(1) track_id 
From
(select track_id, sum(sale_amt) total 
from dbo.Track_Daily_Sales 
group by track_id 
order by total
) abc
```

I am getting an error i.e The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

i want to use top over the subquery with order by inside the sub query, is this possible...

Comment: Please post your query with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Use row_number() over ( order by col) instead

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the `top(1)` usage and the `dbo` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example, you don't need the subquery at all if ties aren't a concern:

```
select top 1 track_id
from dbo.Track_Daily_Sales 
group by track_id 
order by sum(sale_amt)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ebd65/1)

---

Here's an approach with `rank()` to handle ties:

```
select track_id
from (
  select track_id, rank() over (order by sum(sale_amt)) rn 
  from Track_Daily_Sales 
  group by track_id 
  ) t
where rn = 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ebd65/2)